# Openfire: Broadcast message with specific person using smack on android

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I want to create a broadcast list with some specific number of person using smack and openfire. 
I referred smack documentation but i didn't get any proper documentation.
Anyone know how to create it please help me.

Comment: Openfire libraries are lacking proper documentation. Hope they understand the need of developers and provide with it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [broadcast](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/broadcast/readme.html)  pluguin in openfire